# Access to android files like( manifest.xml ) from expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to know how can I access to android or ios files when I create a project with expo XDE?
like (android manifest.xml) or all files which I access to them when I create a project with this command react-native init ?

Answer (score 1):

Expo is managing ios and android files internally. If you want to edit platform specific files you should eject your project. You can simply run this command at root directory of your project folder:

> react-native eject

This command will create ios and android folder at root directory of your project.

> More info please look at:[Gist](https://gist.github.com/ndejesus1227/0eb673452c34e085b3f04fd5c1cbcc9f)